# Change base URL in vue (apps based on “pwa” and “webpack-simple” templates)

Tags: webpack, vuejs2, webpack-dev-server, nginx-reverse-proxy

**I need some help with setting up two vue apps (webpack based) behind a reverse http proxy on one domain - the domain shared between them and other apps, because each should have a different /base/ in the URL.**

---

**Description**

I have to vue apps on private network server with IP 10.0.0.1

- first app **“myapp”** based on vue **“webpack-simple”** template - I want it under **/myapp/** base URL
- second app **“mypwa”** based on vue **“pwa”** template - I want it under **/mypwa/** base URL

So it would look like this:

- RELEASE (dist builds of the apps):

  - https:// mydomain . com /**myapp**/ -> http:// 10.0.0.1:1000/myapp/
  - https:// mydomain . com /**mypwa**/ -> http:// 10.0.0.1:2000/mypwa/
  - https:// mydomain . com /**myapi**/ -> some API on another web server (release version of the API)
- DEVELOPMENT (dev servers with live reload):

  - https:// temp . mydomain . com /**myapp**/ -> http:// 10.0.0.1:1001/myapp/
  - https:// temp . mydomain . com /**mypwa**/ -> http:// 10.0.0.1:1001/mypwa/
  - https:// temp . mydomain . com /**myapi**/ -> some API on another web server (development version of the API)

---

**The help I need here**

1. I need to know *how to setup the vue app and its webpack config* to work for the above scenario.

   - this means changing `/basepath/` of application's stuff for both the dist build and dev-server
   - (I already know that the base URL for hot reload/hot replace cannot be changed because it is hardcoded, so we can skip that)
2. **I have put more details and precise descriptions under [this post on Vue Forum](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/change-base-url-based-on-pwa-and-webpack-simple-templates/18048)**.

   - I already found out the answers to "webpack-simple" template, but "pwa" template seems too hard, so please help.
3. I DO KNOW how to configure nginx reverse proxy, including websockets, so I don’t need help with that.

Comment: Do you use `vue-router`?

Comment: @imcvampire Yes, the "pwa" template already includes vue-router.

I also added vue router to my "webpack-simple" based app and it works nice after rebasing to /somebaseurl/

Anyway I am not worried about vue-router, because - as I think I understand - it operates on the part behind the #, but I talk about everything before the #, i.e. I need all the assets and stuff to be loaded properly. 

So far I made it so that "webpack-simple" based app everything's working (quite simply actually), but still not in "pwa" based app. I described this in my forum update post #2 (link in OP)